# Icon setting in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt

In following fragment of code I try to set loading icon inside label, then I create a delay and finally assign new value (new icon) to label. Problem is the loading icon doesn't show up at all. After clicking button program freezes and then straight shows up a new icon. Apparently there is something I didn't realize, can someone give me an advice?

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            lbl.setIcon(load);
            int val = getRandomNumber(1, 7);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            switch (val) {
              case 1:
                  lbl.setIcon(ic1);
                  break;
              case 2:
                  lbl.setIcon(ic2);
                  break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you want animation from one Icon to another then you need to use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. The Thread.sleep() will simply prevent the GUI from repainting itself so you will never see the first Icon.

Comment: A [swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) is your simple answer as noted in the above comment, but if you want to understand why we need to use a timer or similar, then I strongly recommend running through the official tutorial on [concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), specifically the [concurrency in swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial. They explain how threads/concurrency works and why it is so important.

Comment: Side note: you have 13 answered questions without accepted answers. Please check and make sure that there are no acceptable answers to those questions.